# Calculator with non repeated operations jQuery

Tags: jquery, calculator

I want to make a calculator using jQuery that does not allow the user to input two operations after each other like -- or ++ or ** or // I want the calculator to reset the value to "" <-- empty and also at the same time I don't want the user to input operation at first so there must be a number before the operation how.

Here is my code please help me with it

Note : I am a beginner so excuse me for this primitive question.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var expr="";
        function keypressed(pressedKey){
            expr+=pressedKey;
            document.getElementById("output").value = expr;

        }
        function printresult(){
            var res = eval(expr);
            expr +="=";
            expr +=res;
            document.getElementById("output").value = expr;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <input type="text" id="output" size="15">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick='keypressed("1");
                '></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick='keypressed("2");
            '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick='keypressed("3");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="C" onclick='expr="";
                '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick='keypressed("4");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick='keypressed("5");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick='keypressed("6");
            '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick='keypressed("*");
                '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick='keypressed("7");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick='keypressed("8");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick='keypressed("9");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick='keypressed("-");
                '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="." onclick='keypressed(".");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick='keypressed("0");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick='keypressed("/");
                '></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick='keypressed("+");
                '></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <input type="button" value="         =         "          onclick='printresult();'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a little fiddle, maybe it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/y21ghazh/

I added two new functions:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  var matches = n.match(/\d+/g);
  if (matches != null) {
      return true;
  }

  return false; //No number
}

function checkDuplicateOperator(expr, nextChar)
{
    if(expr.length <= 0)
        return true;
    //Check if the last char of the expression is a non numeric(+,-,/ etc..) value AND
    //If the next char is a non numeric value => This would result in ++ or +- or +/ ... abort!
    if(!isNumeric(expr[expr.length-1]) && !isNumeric(nextChar))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

The first checks if a numeric character is inside the string. Needed to check if the first character is a number and to check if the last character of your expression is a number.

The second function checks if the last charcater is operator like + - / *.
If so, it returns false and no

---

Let me explain:
Your first character has to be a number and you do not want double operators:
So you have to discard the keys in your keypressed() function:

Pseudo Code:

```
//expr is empty and first char is NOT NUMERIC => ABORT!
if(expr.length == 0 AND pressedKey != NUMERIC)
 return; //Abort
else
{
    //pressed key is an operator and the last char of expr is an operator? ==> ABORT!
    if(pressedKey is OPERATOR AND expr.LastKey is OPERATOR)
        return; //Abort
    else
    {
        expr += pressedKey;
    }
}
```